# How to add a command to the linker in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, linker

I try to compile my C++ code in Visual Studio Code but every time I get the following error:

> undefined reference to ...

I have to add `-lgdiplus-lgdi32` to my compiler/linker options. How can I do this in Visual Studio?

This is a part of my `task.json` file:

```
"args": [
    "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
    "-g",
    "${file}",
    "-o",
    "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
    "-lgdiplus",
    "-lgdi32"
],
```

Comment: That should go in linker options, not compiler options.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're under linux(otherwise the process only shows different paths/compilers)
Under the .vscode folder, there should be a `task.json` file.
You should find something similar to:

```
"command": "/usr/bin/g++",
"args": [
    "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
    "-g",
    "${file}",
    "-o",
    "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
 ],
```

Add your arguments to the argument list, enjoy

If there's no file named like that nor you have the folder `.vscode` in your workspace, click `F5` and follow the instructions, and this will generate the necessary files for you.

Comment: I did it but it still doesn't compile

Comment: What's the error now and before? And which commands did you try before writing your questions?

Comment: Still the same: undefined reference and also collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: I posted my task.json file

Comment: I suggest you to improve your question a bit, so we can have a better understanding of the environment: commands you used, a [minimale working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and stacktrace

Comment: Sure, will do that!

Comment: Nice, next check you have those libraries in your system